# How to fix React.Children.only expected to receive a single React element child in react.js?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, redux, components

I am working on a react app with redux for state management but getting the following error while rendering the app.

On `npm start` a blank white screen gets rendered with following error in the console.

```
react.development.js:220 Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `children` of type `array` supplied to `Provider`, expected a single ReactElement.
    at Provider (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:87358:27)

react.development.js:1139 Uncaught Error: React.Children.only expected to receive a single React element child.
    at Object.onlyChild [as only] (react.development.js:1139)
    at Provider.render (Provider.js:60)
    at finishClassComponent (react-dom.development.js:17485)
    at updateClassComponent (react-dom.development.js:17435)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:19073)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:3945)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:3994)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4056)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:23964)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:22776)
```

Here's my `app.js` and `index.js`:

`index.js`

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import App from "./App";
import "./index.css";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import configureStore from "../src/clientDashboard/configureStore";
import { combineReducers } from "redux";
import clients from "../src/clientDashboard/actions/clientReducer";
import Layout from "./clientDashboard/Layout";
export default combineReducers({
  clients: clients,
});

const store = configureStore();
ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    {<App/>},
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

`app.js`

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import logo from "./logo.svg";
import "./App.css";
import Layout from "./clientDashboard/Layout";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import { Button } from "semantic-ui-react";

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Layout />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Here's my `Layout component` for your reference:

```
import { Grid, Form } from 'semantic-ui-react';
import Typography from './ui-components/Typography';
import Table from './Table/Layout';
import Input from './SearchInput';
import styled from './constants/style/styled';
import colorPalette from './constants/style/colorPalette';
import CreatePopup from './Form/Popup';


const StyledTypography = styled(Typography)`
  padding-right: 8px ;
`;


const StyledGridRow = styled(Grid.Row)`
  padding-top: ${props => props.paddingtop} !important;
  padding-bottom: ${props => props.paddingbottom} !important;
`;


const Layout = () => (
  <div>
    <Grid columns='equal'>
      <Grid.Row>
        <Grid.Column textAlign='left' width={13}>
          {console.log("grid-col")}
          <Typography color={colorPalette.instaGrey7} size='big' bold className='inline'>clients</Typography>
        </Grid.Column>
        <Grid.Column width={3} textAlign='right'>
          {console.log("popup")}
          <CreatePopup position='bottom right' triggertext='client' width='calc(100vw - 300px)' />
        </Grid.Column>
      </Grid.Row>
      <StyledGridRow paddingbottom='5px'>
        <Grid.Column width={6}>
          <Typography color={colorPalette.instaGrey7} size='small' bold className='inline'>{'ui.label.client.list.allcaps'}</Typography>
          {console.log("typo")}
        </Grid.Column>
        <Grid.Column textAlign='right' width={10}>
          <Form>
            {console.log("form")}
            <StyledTypography color={colorPalette.instaGrey7} size='small' className='inline'>{'ui.label.search.client'}</StyledTypography>
            <Input />
            {console.log("input")}
          </Form>
        </Grid.Column>
      </StyledGridRow>
      <StyledGridRow paddingtop='5px'>
        <Grid.Column>
          <Table />
        </Grid.Column>
      </StyledGridRow>
      {console.log("gridnnd")}
    </Grid>
   {console.log("div")}
  </div>

);


export default Layout;
```

P.S: I tried wrapping the index.js render element with `React.Navigator` but still getting the error.

Any help will be appreciated.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand the problem is here:

```
  <Provider store={store}>
    {<App/>}, <- error is here, remove {} and ,
  </Provider>
```

You are trying to set multiple React Elements, you first Element is `{<App/>}` and the second one `,`, but `Provider` requires only one item. 
You should change your code to the following:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import App from "./App";
import "./index.css";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import configureStore from "../src/clientDashboard/configureStore";
import { combineReducers } from "redux";
import clients from "../src/clientDashboard/actions/clientReducer";
import Layout from "./clientDashboard/Layout";
export default combineReducers({
  clients: clients,
});

const store = configureStore();
ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App/>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

Hope, it helps